# Images in list disappear when absolute positioning is applied to them

Tags: html, css

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6%;
}

#header li {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25%;
    list-style: none;
}
```

In this header unordered list there are 4 images, but only the first image appears under this code. I've been trying to make them appear in a row rather than a column without the use of float, but I can't get it to show up that way.

Comment: because your position absolute tells all images to be 25% from the right.... they are stacked on-top of each other take that out and give it Display: inline;

Comment: expected output http://jsfiddle.net/kmvvG/ ???

Comment: That's the expected output, yes, but that's not what appears for me(and considering the only other thing in this file are fonts, there should be nothing else affecting it).

Comment: I've taken Beninner's excellent fiddle, and added your code below it. VikingBlooded stated that all four images are stacked on top of each other, and you can see that below Beginner's "real" output.http://jsfiddle.net/kmvvG/5/